# webpack errors with DTO objects generated from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have DTOs written in TypeScript that are then used in files which are packed by webpack, but the resultant bundle generates runtime errors since webpack is not bundling the javascript files from the TypeScript DTO files.

Looking through the documentation of webpack has not resulted in discovering a way to do a blind include of all javascript files in a directory.

==DTO==

```js
module PortalSPA.Models.PurchasePath {
export class SaveModel extends LibSPA.Models.QuoteIdModel {
public FirstName: string
public LastName: string
public CompanyName: string
public DBA: string
public ContactEmail: string
public ContactPhone: string
public ContactExtension: string
public State: string
public ZipCode: string
public MultipleStates: PortalSPA.Models.PurchasePath.FEQuestionModel
}
}
```

```
var extends = (this && this.extends) || (function () {
var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
({ proto: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.proto = b; }) ||
function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
return extendStatics(d, b);
};
return function (d, b) {
extendStatics(d, b);
function () { this.constructor = d; }
d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (.prototype = b.prototype, new ());
};
})();
var PortalSPA;
(function (PortalSPA) {
var Models;
(function (Models) {
var PurchasePath;
(function (PurchasePath) {
var SaveModel = (function (_super) { extends(SaveModel, _super);
function SaveModel() {
return _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
}
return SaveModel;
}(LibSPA.Models.QuoteIdModel));
PurchasePath.SaveModel = SaveModel;
})(PurchasePath = Models.PurchasePath || (Models.PurchasePath = {}));
})(Models = PortalSPA.Models || (PortalSPA.Models = {}));
})(PortalSPA || (PortalSPA = {}));
```

==

Used in another TypeScript file as:

```js
let saveModel: PortalSPA.Models.PurchasePath.SaveModel = {
FirstName: this.FirstName,
LastName: this.LastName,
CompanyName: this.BusinessName,
DBA: this.DBA,
ContactEmail: this.ContactEmail,
ContactPhone: this.ContactPhone,
ContactExtension: this.ContactExtension,
State: this.State,
ZipCode: this.Zip,
MultipleStates: this.MultipleStates,
QuoteId: -1,
QuoteIdEncrypted: null
};
```

This results in a run time error because webpack does not bundle all the DTO files from the DTO directory so references in the bundled javascript files such as LibSPA.Models.QuoteIdModel result in undefined exceptions.

webpack should be able to see that references in the DTO javscript files such as LibSPA.Models.QuoteIdModel mean that it needs to look for the additional javascript files that contain all relevant definitions.  The directory containing the DTOs (both the TypeScript originals and the transpiled javascript reults) are in the source path for webpack so there shouldn't be any reason for webpack to skip any of the files.

Comment: Normally when using webpack, one would use `require` or `import` to "include" code from other modules. Webpack knows how to determine dependencies from those. Not sure about it working with namespaces.

Comment: The problem with ```require``` and ```import``` is that they only take single files.  I have a whole directory filled with the dto files.  Moreover, what's frustrating here is that the dto directory is in the path for webpack to bundle files so it's not as if the directory with the dto files is located outside of the directory structure that webpack traverses.

Comment: [How to use Namespace Typescript properly with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38521466/1441) (i.e. you cannot)

Comment: [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) is how Webpack knows what is used or not (your DTO classes are not `import`ed or `require`d so they are left out). If you don't want to use modules, you probably cannot use webpack.

Comment: It *may* be possible with [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) (I use this to include tests), but I cannot say for sure if the namespace stuff will still work as expected or not.

Comment: what's strange here is that simply being allowed to force a blind include of files in a directory would solve this problem.  I was hoping this webpack would have this capability, but I have not found any reference to such a configuration option.

Comment: what is the webpack solution to DTO files?  The DTO objects that I'm using are being dynamically generated by a template that I created using TypeWriter [link](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/)  This template is dynamically converting C# based DTOs to the TypeScript above.  I developed the template from scratch and can change it.

Comment: Even if they are dynamically created, you still need to know what they are so you can use them, right? If you need a DTO, `import { ThisDTO } from './dtoFolder/thisDto.ts'`. Any that are used are compiled and bundled and any that are not used are not in that process.